# Change Android app Icon in Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I've recently finished my HTML5 app for Android using INTEL XDK , and after all , I exported my project . after I installed it on my device , The app Icon was something related to cordova I guess . I'm just new to these softwares and plugIns . Can you help me out ? I need to change my app Icon . Special Thanks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your icons at the projects page under launch icons 
see screenshot
[image: Choose your icons here]